# Is it possible to download a previous version of minecraft_server.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to set up a Tekkit-like server (+ some different mods). Most mods are not 1.4.2-compatible, yet, so the server runs 1.3.2. I can use MCNostalgia to downgrade the client, but is there any way to downgrade the server or download an old version?

Comment: http://assets.minecraft.net/1_3_2/minecraft_server.jar But I got this link from the pre-release announcement, hence not an answer. Almost all of their builds/old builds are on the assets.minecraft.net site though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it was possible to do this, but couldn't find a way to work out the URL. I just figured it out using MVC (Minecraft Version Changer, mcvc.in), a nice GUI way to download any client or server. I'll submit it as an answer, unless your submit yours. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out with [Minecraft Version Changer (mcvc.in)](http://mcvc.in). It's a nice little Java app to download what ever version you please.

Answer (score 23):

http://assets.minecraft.net/ has all the Minecraft versions since the Beta 1.8 prereleases and **until 1.5.2** inclusive.

To get the needed version of `minecraft_server.jar`, you replace the dots in the version name to underscores and download, for example, [/**1_3_2**/minecraft_server.jar](http://assets.minecraft.net/1_3_2/minecraft_server.jar).

You can also get the *exe* server and the client there. For example:

[/**1_4_3**/Minecraft_Server.exe](http://assets.minecraft.net/1_4_3/Minecraft_Server.exe)
[/**12w32a**/minecraft.jar](http://assets.minecraft.net/12w32a/minecraft.jar)

---

**Since Minecraft 1.6** (and the release of a new launcher) the downloads have been moved to https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/. Examples:

[/versions/**1.6.1**/minecraft_server.**1.6.1**.jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.1/minecraft_server.1.6.1.jar)
[/versions/**13w25c**/minecraft_server.**13w25c**.exe](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/13w25c/minecraft_server.13w25c.exe)
[/versions/**1.6.1**/**1.6.1**.jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.6.1/1.6.1.jar)

Answer (score 2):

MCNostalgia (http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/800346-tool-mcnostalgia) is the generally accepted way to downgrade your Minecraft version. It works based on binary diffs, recalculated on each update for all ~80 something versions archived -- hence it requires an unmodified .jar of the current version.

Some of the available *really* old versions include:

- indev-2-23-10
- infdev-6-18-10
- Alpha 1.0.4, .5_01, .11, .14, .15, .16, .17_02, .17_04
- Alpha 1.1.0, .2, .2_01

After about halfway through Alpha, pretty much every version is available.

Answer (score 2):

If you want newer versions released since this question was asked, the previous answers no longer work, and now it is really easy.

Just open the launcher, create an installation for the version you wish to use, and edit it. There should be a button marked "Download Server", that will do just that.