# Change Minecraft server version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to make a server for me and my friend, but newer versions lag so much for me, so I play version 1.12.2.

How would I change the server version in server.properties?

Comment: wait i just realised you have to install another server.jar im stupeid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to download a previous version of minecraft\_server.jar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92311/is-it-possible-to-download-a-previous-version-of-minecraft-server-jar)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change the server version by modifying a setting in the properties. Instead, you have to replace the `minecraft_server.jar` file in the server folder.

You can get the jar for the version you want to play on from the website [MCVersions.net](https://mcversions.net/). Then just run the server again and it should be on the correct version!