# Where can I find Minecraft old alpha servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a minecraft fan, and also a small youtuber so, can someone help me that where can I get .jar or .exe file of minecraft server a0.1.1, as I want to play and feature this version in one of my videos.

Please help.

Comment: That’s a lost version, it doesn’t have any know existing files.

Comment: This is still a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to download a previous version of minecraft\_server.jar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92311/is-it-possible-to-download-a-previous-version-of-minecraft-server-jar)